# Problem when compile rgbdslam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I compile the rgbdslam in indigo, I meet the problem as below.

```
Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages
[ 46%] Built target RosAria
[ 47%] [ 49%] [ 50%] [ 52%] Building CXX object rgbdslam/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/feature_adjuster.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/sift_gpu_wrapper.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/features.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/aorb.o
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool VideoGridAdaptedFeatureDetector::empty() const’:
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp:203:14: error: ‘detector’ does not name a type
     for(auto detector : detectors){
              ^
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp:206:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
     return false;
     ^
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp:206:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp:206:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp:206:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
/program/Pioneer/src/rgbdslam/src/feature_adjuster.cpp:206:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘return’
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/feature_adjuster.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Do any body have the same problem with me, how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204978/problem-when-compile-rgbdslam/) by [maxtom0](https://answers.ros.org/users/21859/maxtom0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-13

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-14**:
As the wiki says, rgbd slam is for fuerte and rgbdslam v2 is for hydro (stated as beta).

**Comment by [kargas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4888/kargas/) on 2015-06-05**:
Hey buddy did u find out a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could comment out the for loop with "auto detector" and replace with the following block.

```
 for(size_t i=0;i<detectors.size();++i)
 {
     if(detectors.at(i)->empty()) return true;
 }
 return false;
```

Let me know if this solution is ok for you.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1